# Truncated MA(1) one-step-ahead forcast

Tags: forecasting, moving-average

To preface, this is a homework question for me so hints and pointers are what I am primarily looking for, not just the answer.

[image]

I have been having problems with this problem, specifically part b

I have gotten part a to $$E\left[ (x_{n+m} - \tilde{x}_{n+m})^2 \right] = \sigma^2 \sum_{i = 0}^{m-1} \psi_i^2 $$ and I think I am right on this one.

Though for b I am confused, my work so far

$$\tilde{x}_{n+1}^n = - \sum_{i = 1}^{m-1}\pi_i\tilde{x}_{n+1-i}^n - \sum_{m}^{n+m-1} \pi_i\tilde{x}_{n+1-i}^n$$
and for $m = 1$
$$\tilde{x}_{n+1}^n = - \sum_{i = 1}^{0}\pi_i\tilde{x}_{n+1-i}^n - \sum_{1}^{n} \pi_i\tilde{x}_{n+1-i}^n = - \sum_{1}^{n} \pi_i\tilde{x}_{n+1-i}^n$$ 
this is where I am stuck, if my understanding is correct the $\pi$'s are polynomial coefficients for the AR portion of an ARMA process, however this is an MA process and therefore the polynomial is 1. How do I calculate the $\pi$'s then? Are they just one?

This problem is from Time Series Analysis and its Applications 3rd edition by Robert H. Shumway and David S. Stoffer